# Calling javascript-function inside a foreach-loop, wait for reply?

Tags: javascript, ajax, function, loops

I'm a little puzzled on how to solve this.
I have a function updateDate( id ) that updates a specific row in the database with the ID passed along. This function makes an AJAX-call to a PHP-script and it takes a bit of time to run.

I then have this other function called updateDates() which makes an AJAX-call to another PHP-script to get all ID's that needs updating, then loops through these and calls updateDate( id ) with the current ID in the loop.

The problem is that the loop doesn't seem to wait for a response from updateDate( id ) before continuing the loop so it creates like 2398572375 AJAX-calls at the same time and it bugs out.

How can I make the loop wait for a response from updateDate( id ) before continuing?

updateDate( id ) returns true when readyState of the AJAX-call is 4(meaning when the response is done) and I tried in the loop to do:

```
if( updateDate( id ) ) { Do something. }
```

Didn't help.
Any ideas about this?

EDIT: Here's some of the code as requested.

updateDates():

```
                function updateDates()
                {

                    ids = new XMLHttpRequest();

                    ids.open( "GET", "<?php echo anchor("index.php/main/ajax/getIdsToUpdate"); ?>", true );
                    ids.onreadystatechange = function() {

                        if( ids.readyState == 4 )
                        {

                            var response = $.evalJSON( ids.responseText );
                            if( response.type == 1 )
                            {

                                $.each( response.message, function( index, value ) {

                                    if( value != '' )
                                    {

                                        if( updateDate( value ) )
                                            alert('Checked: ' + value);

                                    }

                                });

                            }

                        }

                    }

                    ids.send(null);

                }
```

updateDate( id ):

```
                function updateDate( id )
                {

                    req = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    req.open("GET", "<?php echo anchor("index.php/main/ajax/updateDate/"); ?>" + id, true);

                    req.onreadystatechange = function() {

                        if( req.readyState == 4 ) 
                        {

                            var value = $.evalJSON( req.responseText );

                            // Updating a DIV on the site..

                            return true;

                        }

                    }
                    req.send(null);

                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 good ways to do this without compromising with a synchronous (and locked) UI.

**A. Create a batch update PHP script**

This one's easy enough. Extend your PHP script so that it can take a list of IDs and dates instead of just one at a time. This is the most performant and best solution.

**B. Convert to a queue**

You should convert updateDates() into a dequeuing function. Here's what that means:

Every time updateDates() is called, it pops the first element off the array of IDs you need to update, calls the ajax function, and then sets updateDates as the callback from the Ajax call.

Pseudocode/rough sketch:

```
function updateDates() {
    if(allDates.length == 0) return;

    var data = allDates.unshift();
    $.post('/save.php', { 'id': data.id, 'date': data.date }, updateDates);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I added all my code in the firstpost, is your advice apply-able to my code or is there a better way?

Comment: Yup, it's very general so it works. Any of the solutions similar to mine, particularly the ones advocating batch updates, will work for you and are the best route to choose.

Comment: Did you end up going with route A or route B, or did you need some sort of combination?

Comment: I went route B except I divided it into 2 separate methods. One method fetches all ID's that needs updating via AJAX and onComplete it initiates the recursive method(which is a separate method) that looks pretty much like your route B method :) Only difference is that I did allDates.pop() instead of unshift()

Answer (score 2):

You didn't show much of your code or what you're using to make ajax calls, but you can do something like this pseudo code where you kick of the next ajax call upon the success of the previous one:

```
var idArray = [];   // suppose this is an array of ids that you want to update with individual ajax calls.

function updateNextId(list, index) {
    if (index < (list.length -  1)) {
        ++index;
        var id = idArray[index]
        ajax(parmss, function() {
            // success handler
            updateNextId(list, index);
        });
    }
}
```

A better solution would be to send all the IDs in one ajax call and have the server just deal with multiple IDs.

Comment: I added all the code now in the firstpost! Does your solution still apply to my code or is there a better way?

Comment: Yes it applies.  The general idea is that you keep a list of the ids you want to process, you create a function that processes the next one, you process the first one and then when that one is done (completion callback), you call the function again to process the next one.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I implemented something similar to this and it works great now!

Answer (score 1):

I think the trick is to define a callback that gets called when the AJAX function completes, then call the updateDates function recursively from there.

In pseudo-code:

```
function updateDates(items) {
    current_id = items[0];
    updateDate(current_id, oncomplete: function() {
        next_items = everything_but_current_item(items, current_id)
        updateDates(next_items)
    });
}
```

you may get a stack overflow after a certain amount of recursion, but this is the simplest way to implement I'm thinking.

Comment: Lol.. stack overflow.. nice choice of words ;)
I will check this solution out! Sounds like a good solution

Answer (score 1):

Try using the jQuery looping method `.each()`, jQuery `$.ajax()` and a callback function:

```
$('your element selection').each(function(){
  var thisElement=this;
  $.ajax(url,{
    success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
      //do something to 'thisElement' element with 'data'
    } 
  });
});
```

I agree with the previous poster that a single AJAX call with multiple IDs is better.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX stands for **Asynchronous** Javascript and XML. That means it doesn't wait for a response before continuing. If you want it to wait before continuing, make it [synchronous](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Synchronous_and_asynchronous_requests) instead.

Comment: please never make a synchronous call, you will completely lock up the browser until it completes

Comment: I agree, it defeats the purpose of AJAX, but it's what the OP asked for.

Comment: Perhaps there is another way around it? I provided my code in the firstpost, maybe it changes something?